# No result defined for action after adding an xml validation file

Tags: java, validation, struts2, action, actionresult

I have an action that deletes items from a database. However, when I added a form validation file, I kept getting this error : `no result defined for action and result input` when trying to delete items.

When I delete the validation file, it works fine again. I really don't understand, is it a compatibility issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use validation the `input` result is required to return when errors are found or added. Removing it assumable no validations are performed, so no result is required. It's not a compatibility, just  a resort of things.

Comment: It's not a validation file for deletion, I just added it for form validation. I don't have an input result in my struts.xml for the deletion action.

Comment: Then you should not use validation, add @SkipValidation on action, or override the `excludeMethods` interceptor parameter.

Comment: Thank you, I just got it, I added an intercepetor-ref in my delete action and it worked.